# check buffer size / strncpy

Tags: c, pointers, buffer, strncpy

I'm sure this following question has been asked a lot, but I'll ask btw because I didn't find the answer yet.

I have to recreate the function strncpy (I don't need/want any solution about that) and I cannot reproduce an exact behavior of this function.

This is my code:

```
int main(void)

{

   char dest1[15];

   char dest2[15];

   char *src = "abcdefgh";

   size_t n = 16;

   putstr(strncpy(dest1, src, n);
// the output is : [1]    23975 abort      ./a.out

   putstr(ft_strncpy(dest2, src, n);
// the output is : abcde[1]    23975 abort      ./a.out

   return (0);

}
```

I think the function strncpy check the size of the buffer of dest1 and compare it with n before return something.

The function ft_strncpy is my function, the copy of strncpy.

How can I check the size of the buffer dest2 in my function ? It didn't work with dest2++ (infinite loop) or dest2[index] (return 0);

Edit: Removed the stars of dest1 ans dest2. And added explanation of what is ft_strncpy.

Comment: The code you show is problematic, not because any problem with the `strncpy` function, but with the two arrays. You have two arrays of *pointers* to `char`. In other words, you don't have two arrays that can be used as string, but two arrays *of* strings (or rather potential strings).

Comment: arf, exactly... big mistake. Thank you !

Comment: ok, so it's char dest[15] in my code, bad copy from me. Sorry

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I have to check the error / bad behavior cases of strncpy.

Comment: Anyway: beware of `strncpy`, it may leave you with a nun NUL terminated string.

Comment: you have not allocated memory for your two arrays *dest1 and *dest2

Comment: Your code does not compile at all. `dest1` ist not a `char*`, so your compiler should warn you. And what is `ft_strncpy`?

Comment: Yeah I made a mistake copy of my code there is no * for dest1 ans dest2. ft-strncpy is my function (the copy of strncpy).

Comment: ...and `n` is not 16 but 15 and following `strncpy(dest1, src, n)` _always_ do `dest1[n-1]= '\0';` to be sure the string is terminated.

Answer (score 3):

As for your problem. You *can't* check the size of the destination. All you have is a pointer, and nothing more. You have to rely on the source string or length being smaller than the memory the destination pointer is pointing to.

Also remember that you can't rely on the contents of the destination. Its contents might not be initialized and therefore be *indeterminate*. Arrays or memory in general have no terminator. The string terminator is a *convention*, not something that is enforced by the language.

Answer (score 1):

First to say,  `dest1` and `dest2`, being arrays of type `char *`, wen passed to the function as argument, decay to the address of the first element in the array.

Now, the problem here is, the first element is uninitialized (wild) pointer and any attempt to access the memory pointed by that pointer invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to make sure to make the array elements point to valid memory before you dereference (use) them.

That said,

> *How can I check the size of the buffer dest2 in my function*

Well, you don't. As per the requirement, `strncpy()` does not do that. Also, you cannot do that from the pointer alone, you need to keep track of the allocated memory size yourself, it's not straightaway deducible from a pointer.